# HTML5 basic invirement

Tags: javascript, html

I dont like it when i provide wrong information, so i need some information about HTML5.

> I am not sure, but it seems to me that HTML 5 is just a new flat way of presenting things. They have improved things like CSS styling and video play back. And by the way, they call it HTML 5, but it is actualy JavaScript which does all the work. Please correct me if I am wrong, but this is what I can make of the whole HTML 5 area.

i posted this in a other topic, but i made a mistake confusing javascript with java, and it got deleted.
Ive learned some html5 and to me it realy looks like this way, all i see is Javascript doing the work.

Can someone clarifie this for me, it is important for me to understand this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To oversimplify:

- **HTML** is structure
- **CSS** add visual presentation
- **Javascript** adds behavior

**HTML5** is technically the latest version of the **HTML specification**. {**HTML5**, **CSS3**, **JavaScript**} together are known as the **HTML5 stack**.

There are **3 party components** that can be hosted inside HTML to add additional structure, visual presentation and behavior, but you need **plugins** for them. Most common  components are 
**Java applet**, **Flash player element** and **Silverlight instance**. They are used because things you could do with **old HTML stack** was limited and new **HTML5 stack** was created to remedy that.

Main things for me at least that HTML5 adds

- **drag and drop** support
- new ways to **store data** on local computer to support **Offline Web applications**
- **`<audio>`**, **`<video>`** and **`<canvas>`** to limit the need for 3 party components
- **New tags** to write cleaner code and add **ACCESSIBILITY** support

Comment: With **HTML5** most of **use cases** for **3 party components** are   vanishing. In light of that (and other reasons) **Apple** has dropped support for **Flash** on it's platforms and **MS** has dropped **Silverlight** development. However some of them have their **use case niche** (ex. Computable Document Format).

Comment: I am also well known in Flash and Flex, and Flash can be exported as HTML5, But when u look at the code then, it looks like JavaScript, i think, it has been awhile, and i am learning Android iOS and windows 8 apps at the moment.
aspecialy in the late hours a cant see the beginning or the end of some codes, the next morning i have fixed it in 5 minutes or so.
Flex/Flash builder would be ideal for HTML5, but there is not mutch happening there for the public yet.

Comment: @PeterGruppelaar You can export to HTML5 or HTML + JavaScript in **exceptionally** many ways. However I think **GWT** is even more popular - it converts GWT Java to Javascript and html components with style.

Answer (score 3):

HTML5 is the new web standard, which includes:

- a new document model;
- different HTML syntax;
- new controls, like `audio`, `video`, `input type=range`, `color`, etc;
- old controls removed, like `frame`;
- new javascript elements for History, Storage, IndexDB;
- new layout rules;
- and many, many more.

HTML5 is definitely not a javascript library or extension. Maybe you have just used the javascript functions.

Comment: I went trough some older HTML5 lessons witch had the sql lite still enabled.
I am working allot in php/html5 and i am doing fine, but do you think i need to learn more about html5?

is it possible to let html5 check for a domain name, and display divs, according to witch domain is used?
If this is not possible then i dont need to upgrade my html5 knowledge right now.

Comment: You should to keep up with the standards. Just do it along your work or read a book. At least, create some general knowledge of what is does and what is possible.

Comment: Since when was [noscript](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/scripting-1.html#the-noscript-element) removed?

Comment: @Alohci: Read it somewhere. Must be wrong. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Hai thanks i am fine, i just need to keep Javascript and html5 sepperated when i talk about it, I do have one more question about sql lite, any chance if it becomes the standard any day soon?..i think it is not included any more in chrome.

Comment: It's called IndexedDB. And it is in the standard. Web SQL is deprecated and should not be used any more.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're saying is that a lot of examples on the web claiming to showcase what you can do with HTML5 use a lot of javscript. This isn't wrong, but that's not what HTML5 is. HTML5 is the new iteration of HTML and has nothing to do with javascript. It does, however, make a lot of applications that you'd use javascript for easier by providing a richer environment for the javascript code to run in (like the canvas, or audio and video elements).

Comment: Yes, so i am not far off then.

Comment: Except that your wording is very misleading. HTML5 is HTML. It has nothing to do with javascript or CSS (CSS3 happened to be released at more or less the same time as HTML5, so the two often get mentioned together; nevertheless they are different animals). The fact that HTML5 is often showcased together with javscript does not change that.

Comment: Yes i got that part to, i am sorry text and grammar is not my greatist thing.